# How do I find out who is following me on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, followers

On Facebook, someone is following me besides my friends and clicking the number of my followers on my page, brings me to a page for which a search for the word `Follow` comes up with no results (i.e. no references to the word, "Follow" or "Follower" or "Following" etc. on the page).

Timeline:

[image]

`https://www.facebook.com/username/followers`:

[image]

Comment: That is simply not true. When you click on the followers link, all it does it return you to your friends list. The same holds true when you use username/followers - all it does is bounce you to your friends list. I've had other people try and confirm this. https://www.facebook.com/<USERNAME>/followers <-- does nothing but return you to your Friends list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the 'followers' feature enabled, you can see your list of followers by clicking the 'followers' tab from your Timeline, under the 'Friends' section:

[image: followers link]

It's also available at `https://www.facebook.com/<USERNAME>/followers`

Comment: For me there is no "More" drop down menu; see my latest edit for some more info

Comment: What happens when you click '1 person' in the sentence 'followed by 1 person'?

Comment: Apparently I wasn't clear enough when I said it in my question, sorry, my fault, `.../username/followers`

Comment: Goes to that page and if ya look above, in my question, you can see what that `/username/followers` looks like in the place where you suspected I would see a "More" drop-down menu with Followers in it

Comment: Maybe the person following you also has you blocked or something, which would make that a bug in Facebook's interface for showing you the '1 follower', but i can't reproduce the problem of the view itself not loading

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but I think I've figured it out in the usual confusing Facebook way here: https://www.facebook.com/help/www/216792731707396?rdrhc

> Note: If you already allow people to follow you, **people who send friend requests that you ignore, delete or hide will automatically start following you**. If you don’t want a specific person to follow you, you can block them at any time.

Answer (score 0):

This link shows you your followers. You can just write "My Followers" in the Search bar.
https://www.facebook.com/search/me/followers